# Add Exception Handling to ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr

When I have a grammar called, e.g.

```
interpret
 : (op ';')*
 ;
```

Is it possible to add throw clauses like `throws SQLException`? Every time I compile the Grammer with ANTLR, my Parser throws errors because I did not add any throw clauses to the concrete methods.

I'm asking this cause the rules call methods that use given SQL-database-connection and so I have to add the declarations.

```
public final void op() throws RecognitionException {
```

I want to add `SQLException` and `ClassNotFoundException` automatically on building antlr-generated files (Lexer, Parser).

Regards,
redstreak

Comment: Just a reminder: You can accept an answer by clicking its check mark on the left, if it solved your problem. You can also upvote an answer by clicking the up arrow on the left, if it was useful.

Comment: thanks, i checked the mark, but i am not able to push the arrow up because my reputation is not at 15 at all :(

Comment: No problem, there is no need for you to upvote. I just wanted to clarify how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 24 of the [ANTLR Reference Manual](http://www.antlr.org/share/1084743321127/ANTLR_Reference_Manual.pdf) it says:

> To specify that your parser (or tree parser rule) can throw a
>   non-ANTLR specific exception, use the exceptions clause. For example,
>   here is a simple parser specification with a rule that throws
>   MyException:

```
class P extends Parser;

a throws MyException
  : A
  ;

ANTLR generates the following for rule a:

public final void a() 
  throws RecognitionException,
         TokenStreamException,
         MyException
{
  try {
    match(A);
  }
  catch (RecognitionException ex) {
    reportError(ex);
    consume();
    consumeUntil(_tokenSet_0);
  }
}
```

It seems that this wasn't implemented in earlier versions: [throwing non-antlr exceptions](http://antlr.1301665.n2.nabble.com/throwing-non-antlr-exceptions-td6264835.html)
Fortunately, in the [ANTLR 3.4 Release Notes](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+3.4+Release+Notes), it says:

> Implement the 'throwsSpec' feature of parser rules for the Java target

Just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, in antlr-3.2 it didn't work for me, so as you told me i added antlr-3.4. as general lib and everything works fine. Thank you :)